# How to enable debug symbols in fluentbit binary

Tags: docker, kubernetes, fluent-bit

I'm building Fluent Bit binary with debug symbols enabled in a Dockerfile.
fluentbit version: 2.1.4

When the fluentbit binary runs in my container, it crashes and I don't see the detailed backtrace.
-DFLB_DEBUG=On is the option to enable debug symbols according to fluentbit documentation

I'm building Fluent Bit with debug symbols enabled in a Dockerfile using the following CMake command:

```
`RUN cmake -DFLB_RELEASE=On \        
      -DFLB_TRACE=On \
      -DFLB_BACKTRACE=On \
      -DFLB_DEBUG=On \
      -DFLB_JEMALLOC=On \
      -DFLB_TLS=On \
      -DFLB_SHARED_LIB=Off \
      -DFLB_EXAMPLES=Off \
      -DFLB_HTTP_SERVER=On \
      -DFLB_IN_EXEC=Off \
      -DFLB_IN_SYSTEMD=On \
      -DFLB_OUT_KAFKA=On \
      -DFLB_OUT_PGSQL=On \
      -DFLB_NIGHTLY_BUILD="$FLB_NIGHTLY_BUILD" \
      -DFLB_LOG_NO_CONTROL_CHARS=On \
      -DFLB_CHUNK_TRACE="$FLB_CHUNK_TRACE" \
  ..`
```

Am I giving correct command while building the binary with debug symbols or I'm missing something?